# Finding the common element and the neighbor of the element in a two-dimensional array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, arraylist

```
list = [[2,4], [4,3], [7,6], [8,2], [9,11], [10,11], [13,18], [10,23]]
```

I have a 2D array. If there is any common element in these nested arrays, I want to include the common element and the element next to it in a new array. I give an example array above.
I want to add common elements and neighbors to an array like below.

```
list_dup_out = [[2,3,4,8], [9,10,11,23]]
```

Can you share a sample python code about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd keep a dict of all the associations and then dump the items with multiple associations into a set to dedupe them:

```
>>> arr = [[2,4], [4,3], [7,6], [8,2], [9,11]]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for x in arr:
...     for y in x:
...         for z in x:
...             if y != z:
...                 d[y].append(z)
... 
>>> sorted({y for x in d.values() for y in x if len(x) > 1})
[2, 3, 4, 8]
```

Comment: what can i do if my list is like this and i want to keep different common elements and neighborhoods in different list?   arr = [[2,4], [4,3], [7,6], [8,2], [9,11], [12,11], [13,15], [17,11]]   list_dup_out = [[2,3,4,8],[9,11,12,17]] @Samwise